# tqdm for loop indicator does not work on for loop using "product"

Tags: python, tqdm

I want to use tqdm on a for loop that might be a bit weird and it doesn't work.
Here is the for loop in question:

```
for (Lm1, La1), (Lm2, La2) in tqdm(product(product(Lm_values, La_values), product(Lm_values, La_values))):
```

And here is what tqdm shows:
[image: TQDM error]

Is it impossible to use tqdm in that case?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I don't see why `tqdm` would care about what values the iterable it wraps provides. What are you doing *in* the loop?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (we don't even know what is `product`. Is it `itertools.product`?) and an explanation about what was the expected result (this one seems fine to me. But maybe you were expected an ETA? You can't have an ETA without specifying how many iterations are exepected).

Comment: `product()` is apparently a generator that tqdm cannot find the length of.  You would need to calculate the length yourself (from the lengths of the inputs), and pass that as a `total=` parameter to `tqdm()`.

Comment: If that is `itertools.product`, and if `Lm_values` and `La_values` are arrays (I mean, are anything whose you can compute a length, without "consuming" it), then, total number of iterations is `(len(Lm_values)*len(La_values))**2`. And therefore, `tqdm(...., total=(len(Lm_values)*len(La_values))**2` should do the trick.

Comment: If `Lm_values` and `La_values` are iterator themselves, you need to duplicate them first, (with `itertools.tee`) and then compute the length, and then the `total` argument, with one copy, and use the other copy for the iteration.  But that would pose the question "how much iterations should I do to compute how many iterations I need". On another hand, if that were the case (if `L*_values` were iterators), your code would probably not work as intended (since you use them twice). Point is, it is hard to tell anything accurate without a [mre]. You end up with too much `if` in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Than you for your answers, adding the "total=(len(Lm_values)*len(La_values))**2" argument did the trick.

Have a nice day.